# What #if preprocessor directive to determine if OS is WIN 7 SP1?

Tags: windows-7, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'd like conditional compilation based on whether the compiling machine is running Windows 7 SP1 or not.

We have a workaround for http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589 but I don't want to check the code in unless it is guarded by an #ifdef _WIN7_SP1 otherwise the other devs won't be able to compile it on their non win7-sp1 machines.

I've had a bit of a google but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: since all devs on Win7 should be on Win7 SP1, and you produce production builds from a known build machine (right?), can't you simply assume that all compiling machines require this fix?

Comment: No. Not all devs are on Win 7 SP1. Production builds aren't the problem - we have a build machine (not SP1) for those. It's the dev builds (for the two of us on SP1) that we then put on our testing machines.

Comment: perhaps fix the cause rather than symptoms? I mean how hard is it to apply a service pack? Or are there reasons to remain on Win7 RTM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  Things in the environment of the build machine generally don't pollute compilation like that. (Imagine if that happened and what effects it would cause on reproducibility of builds.)

If you really need to, I'd instead have your build system (make, Visual Studio, whatever) execute a program that checks the current Windows version and fails as necessary (or possibly your build system can determine this already).  Based on that, you then could conditionally make own `WIN7_SP1` definition via a command-line argument to your compiler.

Comment: There will be cases when we are at customer sites where will have to deploy developer builds - might not even have (reliable) internet access so can't use the build machine at home base. Many customer machines are still Win XP. But James, I think you're right. I'll have to make my own def for WIN7_SP1 in the build (or just never check in the 2 problematic header files, so I don't break the other dev's builds :-)